# How can I see my notifications only every hour?

Tags: applications, notifications, productivity

Let me apologize in advance for the bad title, but I didn't quite know how to describe it. What I want is a way for my phone to only show me the notifications from time to time instead of showing them to me as soon as they pop up.

So instead of showing me the notifications from every app as soon as they appear (which is the default) I want a way for Android to keep them hidden and just show, for example, all the notifications for the last hour at once. Then an hour from then it would show me all the notification from that hour, and so on.

I have looked at ways to do this using Android settings itself and I've looked for apps that do that, but no luck. Is there a way to do such a thing?

Thank you.